# XML / XSL Use maths functions like cosine() or sine()

Tags: xml, xslt, math, pie-chart, xls

I have got a XML file. I'm trying to do a pie chart thanks to a XSL file, however I need use maths functions in my program but I don't know how to do it.
In order to visualize the result I want to use a browser like Firefox or Internet Explorer.
Excuse me if I have made mistakes.

Help me please !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers only support XSLT 1.0 and there are no trigonometric functions in XSLT 1.0. I believe your options are limited to these two:

1. Transform your XML to HTML and use HTML/Javascript to draw the chart
   **after** the transformation;
2. Use the Taylor power series to simulate trigonometric functions such
   as sine and cosine.

--
*(Or do the transformation in another tool before passing the result to a browser.)*